# Undefined variable in a method of a class - PHP

Tags: php

I would like to know why my following code doesn't work. It is giving me this error:

> ( ! ) Notice: Undefined variable: uname in C:\wamp\www\oops\visibility-levels\public.php on line 8

```
<?php
class User
{
    public $uname = "admin";

    public function setUsername()
    {
        $this->uname = $uname;
    }

    public function getUsername()
    {
        return $this->uname;
    }
}

$user = new User();
$user->setUsername();
echo $user->getUsername();
?>
```

But when I modify my above code to -

```
<?php
class User
{
    public $uname;

    public function setUsername($uname)
    {
        $this->uname = $uname;
    }

    public function getUsername()
    {
        return $this->uname;
    }
}

$user = new User();
$user->setUsername("admin");
echo $user->getUsername();
?>
```

Then it works fine and gives me following output -

> admin

But I dont understand why I got undefined variable uname in my first segment of code. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because function setUserName doesn't know value of variable $uname, you need to define it inside the scope, or pass via function argument.

for example:

```
public function setUsername()
{
    $uname = 'foo';

    $this->uname = $uname;
}
```

will result in output: foo

Answer (score 0):

Variable `$uname` is undefined in the setUsername function scope. Use `$this->uname` to access class variable or put $uname as a parameter (and you will have local `$uname` variable in the function).

Answer (score 0):

In the `setUsername` function, the variable `$uname`, is never defined. You are trying to set the class attribute `$this->uname` to a non-initialized variable.

In the working code the `$uname` variable is initialized when the parameter is passed to the function.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function setUsername() // <-- missing $uname in args
{
    // $uname is like Javascripts Undefined here,
    $this->uname = $uname;
}
```

The error is exactly originating from `= $uname;` - it doesn't exist unless defined as a parameter in the argument list.

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you want the first functionality:

```
<?php
class User
{
    public $uname;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->uname = "admin";
    }

    public function setUsername($uname)
    {
        $this->uname = $uname;
    }

    public function getUsername()
    {
        return $this->uname;
    }
}

$user = new User();
$user->setUsername();
echo $user->getUsername();
?>
```